# In Solr, are filter queries with a cost also cached?

Tags: solr, filter

I am reading the excellent [Solr in Action](http://www.manning.com/grainger/) book, and in chapter 7 about querying, it first states that filter queries (e.g. `fq=title:"Solr in Action"`) have the benefit that they are often reusable between searches and that their results can be cached independently. It goes on to describe the process of executing a query and that

> ...the filter is executed against the index to obtain a new `DocSet`...

Later on, when explaining the `cost` local param (e.g. `fq={!cost=42}title:"Solr in Action"`) it states that

> ...if filters that reduce the results set the most can be executed first, any additional filters then have fewer documents to act upon and will therefore execute faster.

This seems contradictory to me. If say a 2nd filter only considers the `DocSet` yielded by the 1st filter, then it wouldn't make sense to cache the 2nd filter's result. It would not be reusable for the next search, since the next search might not have that 1st filter.

Does applying cost to a filter query imply that it will no longer be executed against the index but agains the results of all previous filters? If so, how does that affect cacheability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's late, but I've faced with the same question, so I'll post answer here.

[Here](http://solr.pl/en/2012/03/05/use-of-cachefalse-and-cost-parameters/) : "You should remember that cost attribute work only when the filter query is not cached."
[And here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-Thecache=falseParameter)

So, "cost" is only for non-cached filters.